# I'm not able to change h3 from app.js after getting data from api server

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, https

I'm trying to change element h3 of index.html when I receive data from API server
code of index.html

```
    <form action="/" class="" method="POST">
          <h1 class=""><span class="clr-dark-purple">VPN</span> & <span class="clr-dark-purple">Proxy</span> Detection.</h1>
          <h2>Test to see if an IP address is either a VPN, Proxy, or a TOR node</h2>

          <input type="text" name="ip"  class="css-input" placeholder="Enter IP Address" required autofocus> <br>
          <div class="container-one">
    <button type="submit">
    Test
      <div class="fill-one"></div>
    </button>
  </div>

          <h3></h3>
        </form>
```

code in app.js

```
 app.get("/",function(req,res)
{
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.post("/",function(req,res){
  const apikey = "my-api-key";
  const ip = req.body.ip;

  const url = "https://vpnapi.io/api/" + ip + "?key=" + apikey +"";

  console.log(ip, url);

  https.get(url,function(response)
  {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    const chunks = [];
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
     chunks.push(chunk)
   })

   response.on('end', function () {
     const data = Buffer.concat(chunks)
     var deta = JSON.parse(data)
     var vpn = deta.security.vpn;
     var proxy = deta.security.proxy;
     var city = deta.location.city;
     res.write(`<h3><span style="margin-right:1.3em"><span style="color:#301b3f;">VPN:</span> ${vpn}</span><span style="margin-right:1.3em;"><span style="color:#301b3f;">Proxy:</span> ${proxy}</span> <span><span style="color:#301b3f;">City:</span> ${city}</span></h3>
`);

     console.log(vpn,proxy,city);
   })
 })
 });
```

I'm not able to change the content of h3, Help!
Everything else working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Keep `index.html` as it is.

I have commented down some code as I didn't have the API key required in them.

Just replace `res.write()` with `res.send()`.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const https = require('https');

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    //const apikey = "my-api-key";
    //const ip = req.body.ip;

    // const url = "https://vpnapi.io/api/" + ip + "?key=" + apikey + "";
    const url = "https://vpnapi.io/api/";

    //console.log(ip, url);

    https.get(url, function (response) {
        console.log(response.statusCode);
        const chunks = [];
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk)
        })

        response.on('end', function () {
            const data = Buffer.concat(chunks)
            var deta = JSON.parse(data)
            var vpn = deta.security.vpn;
            var proxy = deta.security.proxy;
            var city = deta.location.city;

            console.log(vpn, proxy, city);
            res.send(`<h3><span style="margin-right:1.3em"><span style="color:#301b3f;">VPN:</span> ${vpn}</span><span style="margin-right:1.3em;"><span style="color:#301b3f;">Proxy:</span> ${proxy}</span> <span><span style="color:#301b3f;">City:</span> ${city}</span></h3>
            `);

        })
    })
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Application running on PORT ${port}`);
})
```

Comment: I just want to change the h3 of my index.html with the proper values, thanks for the help.

Comment: If it has solved your issue please mark it as the best answer.